# how to display json response data from controller in blade page in laravel using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, livesearch

i have data returned from conntroller by ajax response in json format and I can print data in console.
but I want to display it in a table, how can I display it?
i made a search for solution but all solution write HTML code in controller function and return it as response, so is there any other solution

my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Category;

class CategoryCtrl extends Controller
{
    //function search - show categories live search
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $categories = Category::where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->cat_search."%")->orderBY('created_at','DESC')->get();
            return Response()->json($categories);
        }
        else {
            $categories = Category::orderBY('created_at','DESC')->get();
            return view('backend.category.list')->withcategories($categories);
        }
    }

}
```

view

```
@extends('backend.layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" id="cat_search" placeholder="Category Search..." />
                   
    <table id="CategoriesTable" class="table table-striped table-vcenter js-dataTable-simple">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th class="text-center w-5">#</th>
               <th class="text-center">Name</th>
               <th class="text-center hidden-xs">Icon</th>
               <th class="text-center hidden-xs">Order</th>
               <th class="text-center w-15">Status</th>
               <th class="text-center">Created At</th>
               <th class="text-center">Last Update</th>
               <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%;">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                    @foreach ($categories as $key=>$category)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center text-capitalize">{{ $category->name }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center hidden-xs"><i class="{{ $category->icon }} fa-lg"></i></td>
                            <td class="text-center hidden-xs">{{ $category->order }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center text-capitalize"> 
                                <span class="btn btn-sm btn-pill @if($category->status == 'active') btn-primary @else btn-warning @endif">{{ $category->status }}</span> 
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ $category->created_at->format("Y-m-d g:i a") }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ $category->updated_at->format("Y-m-d g:i a") }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a href="{{ route('category.edit', ['id' => $category->id]) }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-app" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{ $category->name.$category->id }}">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="{{ $category->name.$category->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-card-header">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <h4 class="col-md-10">Delete Category</h4>
                                                    <ul class="card-actions col-md-2">
                                                        <li>
                                                            <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><i class="ion-close"></i></button>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-block">
                                                <p>Are you sure, you want to delete category (<span class="text-capitalize">{{ $category->name }}</span>) ?</p>
                                                <p>If you delete category, you will delete all category's products too.</p>
                                                <p>Notice: if you want to hide category, you can update it's status to not active instad of delete it.</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                {!! Form::Open(['url' => route('category.delete', ['id' => $category->id]) ]) !!}
                                                    <button class="btn btn-app" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal"> Delete</button>
                                                {!! Form::Close() !!}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Modal -->

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                   
                </tbody>
            </table>
    
@endsection
```

ajax code

```
<!--  Ajax code for category live search  -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#cat_search').on('keyup',function(){
            $value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'get',
                url : '{{ route('category.index') }}',
                data:{'cat_search':$value},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){
                    //console.log(response);
                });

             });
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the best way i can tell is to make a blade for that table and in controller just as usual return data to that view:

```
 return view('your-blade-just-for-table')->with('data', $data);
```

and in your blade again as usual you render your data with laravel in your table

so laravel will return a blade to your ajax-success method

and in your success method you can do something like:

```
    success: function (data) {
            $('.list-group').html(data);
        },
```

and wherever you want your table to be just put this div:

```
<div class="list-group" id="myFileContainer"></div>
```

Comment: that's help, but if i received multiple categories data in response; how to loop and display data?

Comment: you just loop them as usual with laravel in that blade. i dont understand what you mean but there should be no problem

Comment: when i return data to view as usual I can't access the data from success function, and if I return it as response and show it in a div i can't loop it

Comment: you didnt get what i mean i think. did you make a blade that just include the table you want???
did you sent your ajax request to your function and return the data to that blade just like my first line of code?
if you did those you can use next lines of code that i wrote to show your table.
you dont have to access laravel data in your success method

Comment: I missed some lines, but it works now. thanks bro

Comment: if it helped you please mark it as best answer so others can use it too
good luck bro